# C# -> Función que retorna los elementos de un IEnumerable<T> cuyo valor según una función de transformación f de tipo entera es el máximo

Tags: c#

//Función que retorna los elementos de un IEnumerable cuyo valor según una función de transformación f de tipo entera es el máximo.

```
        string[] words = { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "seven" };
        //Devuelve la lista de cadenas con mayor longitud.
        Func<string> Maximo = (str) => (str.Length);
        // DESCOMENTA LA LINEA SIGUIENTE CUANDO IMPLEMENTES Maximo
        IEnumerable<String> maximos = words.Maximo<String>((x)=>x.Length);

        foreach (String word in maximos)
            Console.WriteLine(word)
```

---

Alguien me puede ayudar, no consigo llegar a buscar el maximo del array..

Comment: Y el problema es??????????????????????????

Comment: estaría correcta la funcion?

Comment: No tiene pinta. Esa funcion lo que te va a devolver es la longitud de cada uno de los elementos, si no me equivoco... De todas maneras, es sencillo probarlo y depurarlo paso a paso a ver que resultado te devuelve.

Comment: No veo que se este calculando ningun maximo, ademas porque el codigo esta comantado?

Comment: Si veo bien, se requiere implementar la función ``Maximo()``. Ya existe una versión en LINQ pero supongo que es gol es implementar tu propia versión para aprender… Investiga (a) calcular el máximo de una serie de valores y (b) implementar un método de extensión.